# Basic output with variables

Tags: input, io, output

A variable like user_num can store a value like an integer. Extend the given program as indicated.

Output the user's input. (2 pts)
Output the input squared and cubed. Hint: Compute squared as user_num * user_num. (2 pts)
Get a second user input into user_num2, and output the sum and product. (1 pt)

Given:

user_num = int(input('Enter integer:\n'))

## Type your code here

I have no idea where to start. I have looked through my resources and I dont know which coding formula to follow.

Comment: You didn't look good enough. There are tons of solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

```py
user_num = int(input('Enter integer:\n'))

print(user_num) # Output the user's input
print(user_num * user_num) # Output the input squared
print(user_num * user_num * user_num) # Output the input cubed

user_num2 = int(input('Enter another integer:\n')) #  Get a second user input into user_num2

print(user_num + user_num2) # output the sum

print(user_num * user_num2) # output the product
```